# Java: HTTP post multidimensional array

Tags: java, php, android, http, multidimensional-array

I try to find a way to post a multidimensional array in java but I didn't found any information about this (without JSON).
I already have the serveur side code that handle the request in pure php:

```
$_POST['login'] = '-------';
$_POST['date'] = '8h29%;8h49';
$_POST['command'][0]['quantity'] = 1;
$_POST['command'][1]['quantity'] = 11;
$_POST['command'][0]['id_product'] = 2;
$_POST['command'][1]['id_product'] = 20;
```

So, have you an idea to solve my problem ?

thanks :).

Comment: Why don't want to use JSON?

Comment: I need to fit in the model above. Did you think I can in JSON ? how ?

Comment: if you need to fit the model above, than you have to manually form your POST-body.